# Get current enumerator (iterator ?) in LINQ query. Like a current index in for loops

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-xml

Is that possible to get current Enumerator (...or iterator? Don't know which tern is the correct one) in a LINQ query ?

For example, I try to create a XML output (via LINQ to XML) of all currently loaded assemblies.

```
Dim xmldoc As XDocument = New XDocument(
        New XElement("Types",
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies() _
                .Select(Function(name) Assembly.Load(name)) _
                .SelectMany(Function(assembly) assembly.GetTypes()) _
                .Select(Function(type) New XElement("Type", type.FullName))))
```

Tho output looks like this.

```
<Types>
  <Type>System.Object</Type>
  <Type>FXAssembly</Type>
  <Type>ThisAssembly</Type>
  <Type>AssemblyRef</Type>
  <Type>System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable</Type>
  <Type>System.Runtime.InteropServices._Exception</Type>
  .....
</Types>
```

is it possible to somehow get current "index" (counter?) from LINQ's Selects? I would like to use it in XML

```
<Types>
  <Type ID="1">System.Object</Type>
  <Type ID="2">FXAssembly</Type>
  <Type ID="3">ThisAssembly</Type>
  <Type ID="4">AssemblyRef</Type>
  <Type ID="or-some-other-unique-id-#5">System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable</Type>
      .....
</Types>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yup - you just need to use the [overload of `Select` which takes a `Func<TSource, int, TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx). So in C# it would be something like:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Types",
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()
        .Select(name => Assembly.Load(name))
        .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
        .Select((type, index) => new XElement("Type",
                                              new XAttribute("ID", index + 1), 
                                              type.FullName))));
```

Sorry it's not in VB, but it's more likely to work this way - hopefully you can work out the translation :)

Comment: is it also possible with "normal" (SQL-Like) LINQ queries?

example...

`XDocument xml = new XDocument(New XElement("Items",
from item in someItemsResourses
where item.FullName.length => 5
oderby item descending
select new XElement("item", new XAttribute("id", ?how?), item.FullName)))`

Comment: @V-Light: Yes, but embedding query expressions into other statements always looks odd to me.

Comment: Yes, it sounds pretty rational, but anyway, how can I  implement "counter" in a SQL-Like LINQ query? Just want to know how it looks like. For the case, query expression has to be embedded into another statement :)

Comment: @V-Light: Sorry, I must have been distracted when I wrote the previous comment - I don't know about VB for sure, but C# query expressions don't support that overload of Select - so you can do the *earlier* part in a query expression and then tack the Select call on afterwards, but it can't be part of the query expression itself, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

@V-Light,

You could do something like this to get your iterator index:

```
XDocument xml = new XDocument(New XElement("Items",  from item in someItemsResourses where item.FullName.length => 5 orderby item descending  //Get   Iterator Index here and make use of it as you wish  let currIndex = someItemsResourses.IndexOf(item)  select new XElement("item", new XAttribute("id", ?how?), item.FullName)))
```